# Trying to create circular progress bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint

I am trying to add a circular progress bar to my app in Swift, however I haven't been able to find any Swift specific examples. Therefore, I found the easiest Objective C example and I am trying to translate it into Swift.

This is the example I'm following: [Using circular progress bar with masked image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498390/using-circular-progress-bar-with-masked-image)

I am stuck at this line:

```
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
```

CGRectGetMidX does not seem to be available in Swift.

Here is all of my code so far:

```
    func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var progress: CGFloat = 0.7
    var innerRadiusRatio: CGFloat = 0.5

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var startAngle: CGFloat = -M_PI_2
    var endAngle: CGFloat = -M_PI_2 + MIN(1.0, progress) * M_PI * 2
    var outerRadius: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5 - 1.0
    var innerRadius: CGFloat = outerRadius * innerRadiusRatio
}
```

Where am I going wrong? As well as struggling to translate this line, the other lines have some errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an error on that line at all -- `CGRectGetMidX is still available as far as I can tell:

```
var center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))
```

The other line that gives me errors is this one -- those constants are of type `Double` and need to be converted to `CGFloat`, and in Swift the method is `min` not `MIN`:

```
var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + min(1.0, progress) * CGFloat(M_PI) * 2
```